# how to give the value selected from menu button as input to os.system in python gui

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

the below python gui code i am trying to select the values from the drop down menu buttons(graph and density) and trying to pass them as command line arguments  to os.system command in the readfile() function as shown below but I am having a problem in passing the values I have selected from the drop down menu to os.system command.

import os
    import Tkinter as tk

```
def buttonClicked(btn):
    density= btn 

def graphselected(graphbtn):
    graph=graphbtn

def readfile():
    os.system( 'python C:Desktop/python/ABC.py graph density')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Dense Module Enumeration")

btnList=[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]
btnMenu = tk.Menubutton(root, text='Density')
contentMenu = tk.Menu(btnMenu)
btnMenu.config(menu=contentMenu)

for btn in btnList:
    contentMenu.add_command(label=btn, command = lambda btn=btn: buttonClicked(btn))
btnMenu.pack()


graph_list=['graph1.txt','graph2.txt','graph3.txt','graph.txt']
btnMenu = tk.Menubutton(root, text='graph')
contentMenu = tk.Menu(btnMenu)
btnMenu.config(menu=contentMenu)

for btn in graph_list:
    contentMenu.add_command(label=btn, command =lambda btn= btn: graphselected(btn))
btnMenu.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="DME", command=readfile)

button.pack()    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to implement with [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) - apply needed value to your function for each button. Here is a sample:

```
from functools import partial
import Tkinter as tk

BTNLIST = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]

def btn_clicked(payload=None):
    """Just prints out given payload."""
    print('Me was clicked. Payload: {}'.format(payload))


def init_controls():
    """Prepares GUI controls and starts mainloop"""
    root = tk.Tk()
    menu = tk.Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    sample_menu = tk.Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Destiny", menu=sample_menu)
    for btn_value in BTNLIST:
        sample_menu.add_command(
            label=btn_value,
            # Here is the trick with partial
            command=partial(btn_clicked, btn_value)
        )
    root.mainloop()


init_controls()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, `graph` and `density` are local variables to `graphselected()` and `buttonClicked()`. Therefore, `readfile()` can never access these variables unless you declare them as global in all three functions.

Then you want to format a string to incorporate the values in `graph` and `density`. You can do that using the strings [`.format` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Combining that your three functions become

```
def buttonClicked(btn):
    global density
    density = btn 

def graphselected(graphbtn):
    global graph
    graph = graphbtn

def readfile():
    global density, graph
    os.system('python C:Desktop/python/ABC.py {} {}'.format(graph, density))
```